# Circular views with Autolayout (snapkit)?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

I am trying to make a circular view which has an adaptive size based on auto layout, currently i set the constraints, then i attempt to round the image in the viewwilllayoutsubviews method.

This is resulting in oddly shaped views that are not circular, how can i resolve this?

init:

```
    profilePic = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
    profilePic.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

constrains:

```
 profilePic.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
                make.centerX.equalTo(self).multipliedBy(0.80)
                make.centerY.equalTo(self).multipliedBy(0.40)
                make.size.equalTo(self).multipliedBy(0.22)
            }
```

subviews:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        self.navigationMenuView.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = self.navigationMenuView.profilePic.frame.size.width / 2.0
        self.navigationMenuView.profilePic.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.navigationMenuView.profilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Try adding one more constrain "Aspect ratio" to 1:1 to imageView. Because if you want circle, there must be square imageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this (sorry for the plain autolayout, but I don't use snapkit):

```
profilePic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profilePic.widthAnchor).isActive = true
profilePic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.22).isActive = true
```

Instead of this:

```
make.size.equalTo(self).multipliedBy(0.22)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

This is my solution:

```
let profilePicHeight: CGFloat = 30.0
```

Add this line of code to your constrains:

```
profilePic.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.height.width.equalTo(self.profilePicHeight)
            ...
        }
```

then:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    self.navigationMenuView.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = self.profilePicHeight / 2.0
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here is don't treat it like a circular view from the outside of it. Make the view itself conform to being a circle so that you can use it anywhere.

INSIDE the view give it constraints like...

```
widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

This will make it square (with undetermined size).

Then in the function `layoutSubviews`...

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.width * 0.5
}
```

This will make the square into a circle.

Comment: this is pretty much what the code already does? i make it square in the constraints and then round in subviews

Comment: @jackdm but you're still telling it to be square in the view controller. Would make sense to make the view itself be a square. Also, I question the use of snap kit. Auto Layout is really not hard to do. I'd recommend dropping that and just learning Auto Layout.